# How would I print out the first word of each line?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, bufferedreader

I have a text file that reads like this:

```
1. Bananas that are not green
2. Pudding that is not vanilla
3. Soda that is not Pepsi
4. Bread that is not stale
```

I just want it to print out the first word of each line 
*NOT INCLUDING NUMBERS!*

It should print out as:

```
Bananas
Pudding    
Soda    
Bread
```

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    ArrayList <String> myFileLines = new ArrayList <String>();

    try {
        String sCurrentLine;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                FileReader("/Users/FakeUsername/Desktop/GroceryList.txt"));
        while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(sCurrentLine);               
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            if (reader != null)reader.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `split` function of String. It returns the array of the String as per the character which we want to split with the string. In your case, it is like as follow.

```
 String sCurrentLine = new String();
 reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                FileReader("/Users/FakeUsername/Desktop/GroceryList.txt"));
 while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine() != null) {
    String words[] = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
    System.out.println(words[0]+" "+words[1]);
 }
```

Comment: Actually you want to only print words[1] since the number should not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8+ you can use the `BufferedReader`'s [`lines()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--) method to do this very easily:

```
String filename = "Your filename";
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
reader.lines()
      .map(line -> line.split("\\s+")[1])
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

***Output:***

```
Bananas
Pudding
Soda
Bread
```

---

This will create a `Stream` of all the lines in the `BufferedReader`, split each line on whitespace, and then take the second token and print it

Answer (score -1):

Please try the code below -:

```
outerWhileLoop: 
while ((sCurrentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
     //System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
     StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(sCurrentLine," .");
     int cnt = 0;
     while (st.hasMoreTokens()){
        String temp = st.nextToken();
        cnt++;
        if (cnt == 2){
           System.out.println(temp);
           continue outerWhileLoop;  
        }
    }
}
```